# Python GET request does not work but the same ajax request works. What is wrong with it?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, python-requests

I have a problem with python requests modules. I have written two programs in python and javascript/jquery. Both send a request to the same website without any header. The python one stucks and throws timed out but the JS one works well on the same server with the same IP address. What is wrong about it? (I have added X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest and change the User-Agent from python-requests to Mozilla... to the header but no luck). My codes are following below:

My Python program:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com/test")
```

My JS script:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.example.com/test',
type: "GET",
success: function(result){
    $("div#my_content").text(JSON.stringify(result));
}
});
```

Comment: Can you please show the real url which you are using?

Comment: Is this a public api? Do you need to authenticate against the api? Please provide a error message as your example is too generic right now.

Comment: @Smittie That is open public api. The error is `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`. I wonder why does the ajax work well at the same server!

Comment: @Irfanwani The URL is: `https://search.codal.ir/api/search/v2/q?&Audited=true&AuditorRef=-1&Category=-1&Childs=true&CompanyState=0&CompanyType=1&Consolidatable=true&IsNotAudited=false&Isic=399905&Length=-1&LetterCode=%D9%86-%DB%B3%DB%B1&LetterType=-1&Mains=true&NotAudited=true&NotConsolidatable=true&PageNumber=1&Publisher=false&Symbol=%D8%B4%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7&TracingNo=-1&search=true`